# Modulo Algorithm creation

Tags: algorithm

Alright this is a homework question that I've been wracking my brain about

> Show an Algorithm that on input integers a,b where a is n bit long and b < a, computes a mod b in O(n^2)

I've come up with the following algorithm and I wondered if I'm in the right track:

```
modulus(a,b)
c = a-b;
modulus (c,b)
result c;
```

Would this be correct? Or am I doing it too intuitively? Any tips?

I was trying to write out the algorithm in pseudo code. and yes it's asking about implementing modulus.

Comment: I can only assume that the question is asking you to implement `modulus`.

Comment: This does not make much sense to me. You substitute calculation of `a mod b` by two calculations of some undefined function `modulus (x, y)`. Unless you define that function, your rewrite does not help. (And even if you do define `modulus`, the rewrite will likely be unnecessary.)

Comment: Hmm, the first line might be function name, and the third one a recursive call of that function. Then the code does make a bit of sense (albeit for calculating GCD (a, b), not a modulo b), but is still too slow: consider a = 1000000000 and b = 1, for example.

Comment: I was trying to write out the algorithm in pseudo code. and yes it's asking about implementing modulus.

Comment: Isn't this a question for [programmers.se] not here? (Note to OP: don't repost there. If it makes sense, flag to move instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute a mod b, you have to subtract multiples of b from a until the result is less than b. For simplicity, I'll assume a >= 0, b > 0, but you can use the relations mod(-a, b) = mod(a, -b) = -mod(a, b) to recover the negative-signed cases.

The most naive (but inefficient) way to implement `mod` is this:

```
def mod(a, b):
    while a >= b:
        a -= b
    return a
```

This is awful when a is much larger than b. The complexity is O(a/b) which is O(2^n) in the worst cases where n is the number of bits. Instead, we can try subtracting large multiples of b, and we can do this with bit-shifting.

```
def mod(a, b):
    bs = b
    while bs <= a:
        bs <<= 1
    while bs > b:
        bs >>= 1
        if a >= bs: a -= bs
    return a
```

In this code, we keep shifting b (in the variable bs) left until it's larger than a. Then one step at a time, we shift it back to b, subtracting the value from a if we can. This is essentially an implementation of long division in binary.

As for time complexity: a left-shift is O(n) (assuming we're dealing with arbitrary large numbers where n is the number of bits), as is comparison and subtraction. That makes both of the `while` loops in this implementation O(n^2) as required.

Comment: Wow and thank you for that Anonymous! The naive way to implement mod was what I was trying to do! but the efficientcy works nicely. Both manners are N^2 so thanks.

Comment: No, the inefficient way is O(2^N).

Comment: Gah. Sorry about that!

Comment: Hmm... I think its the shifting that's making me not understand the algorithm well. I think my problem was of thinking the algorithm solely in ints?